# How to dynamically load Vue.js Async Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to allow for different components to be loaded based on a UI selection. In this case, two versions of a single API. I am hoping that I can change the path of the WebPack bundle used based on this selection, but I'm not sure it will work.
I am doing something like:

```
export default {
    props: ['version'],
    computed: {
        path () {
            return this.version + 'component/path';
        }
    },
    components: {
        'dynamic': Vue.component('dynamic' (resolve) => {
            require([this.componentPath], resolve);
        }),
    }
}
```

This does attempt to load the bundle and that works. However, because `this` is the exported object for some reason `this.default.componentPath()` is not a function and of course `this.componentPath` (as written in included example) is undefined.
My intention with this is to be able to load single file components located at paths like `1.0/Category/Method` and `2.0/Category/Method`.

1. Will this component path be changed when `version` changes? It's bound with `v-model` to a select input.
2. What is the *correct* way to do something like this?